# ReactJs - API Feed Error - cannot read property of map undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, array.prototype.map

I was hoping you could help me out.  I'm trying to plugin a simple TFL tube API into my web page, using axios/ReactJs.

The integration is really simple.  I'm using app.js and then a functional component, where I'll loop/map over the data and pull out the information I need into my webpage, via `<li>`s.

However, I keep getting the following error in my `<Frame />` component:

```
app.js:29827 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of 
undefined at Frame (app.js:29827)
```

It's doesn't like how I'm mapping over 'feed'. I'm not sure what I've missed, as usually this code works for simple API integrations.

**Here's the app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Frame from './components/Frame';
import 'bulma';


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('CONSTRUCTOR');

    this.state = {
      feed: []
    };
  }

 //pull through the TFL data
 componentDidMount() {
  console.log('tfl feed');
   axios.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Mode/tube/Status?detail=true&app_id=IVEREMOVEDAPIID&app_key=IVEREMOVEDAPIKEY')
  //response
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
    console.log(res.data[0].name);
    this.setState(
      { feed: res.data });
  });
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <section>
        <div>
          <h1>Tube Status</h1>
          <Frame />
        </div>
      </section>
     );
    }
   }


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**And here's the the `<Frame />` module, that I'm doing my mapping in:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Frame = ({feed}) => {

return (

<section>
  <div className="columns is-multiline">
    <ul>
      {feed.map((tube, i) => <li className="column is-one-quarter" key={i}>
        {tube.name}
      </li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
  );
};

export default Frame;
```

Any pointers, would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`feed` `undefined` because you not pass the props to component. See your render method.

Just pass feed peace of state to `Frame` as props.

```
render() {
 return(
   <section>
     <div>
       <h1>Tube Status</h1>
       <Frame feed={this.state.feed}/>
     </div>
   </section>
  );
 }
}
```